# AWS Sagemaker Studio Local Ram Overload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Every time i open studio and get to the jupyter labs page about 10s seconds later the browser starts to eat local ram at ~0.1GB/s and one or two cores max out at 100% utilization.

It will continue doing this until all local ram on **my local computer** has been used up and then it overloads the swap and everything freezes requiring reboot.

This happens with Firefox, Chrome, and Gnome browser. I have yet to try this on windows, if possible I would like to get this working with my current environment.

If it helps:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, 64 bit
Intel i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8
GeForce GTX 1060

In all cases there is a rather large spike in bandwidth corresponding with the start of the issue. 
~7+ MBs for ~2 seconds. This seems to correspond with a fetch request being made. 

The process name consuming the memory and CPU when using chrome appears to be:
chrome -type=renderer followed by a bunch of other stuff

Occasionally the page will crash before using all the ram the error message on chrome is:
Error code: SIGTRAP

If the sagemaker jupyter labs tab is killed or the browser is closed before ram maxes out.
The cores it is maxing out go to normal utilization and the ram is released.
```